# RestoreGeometry() with multi-monitor configuration

Tags: c++, qt, position, window, location

I have a `QMainWindow` and wish to remember its size and position on the screen.

This I can do with `saveGeometry()`, to save the settings to a `.ini` file and `restoreGeometry()` - to restore the window.

However, what will be the `behaviour` of the Window on a `multiscreen` setup?

Is it possible for the Window to be launched on the correct calling window, and with its size and position on that window remembered?

In my current implementation, I have taken care of the launch of the application where the mouse pointer currently is, but the window is always full screen, unless someone sets the position manually in the `ini` file.

```
int posX = cSfcConfig::getProperties(MAIN_WINDOW, POS_X).toInt();
int posY = cSfcConfig::getProperties(MAIN_WINDOW, POS_Y).toInt();
QByteArray locationArray = cSfcConfig::getLocationSetting();
if ( posX > 0 || posY > 0)
{
    QRect rect = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry();  
        QDesktopWidget *m=new QDesktopWidget();
        QPoint p= QCursor::pos();
        int r= m->screenNumber(p);
        QRect d=m->screenGeometry(r);
        //QPoint l = d.();
        int width = rect.width() - (posX * 2);
        int height = rect.height() - posY;
        //mainWindow.restoreGeometry(locationArray);
        //mainWindow.restoreState(cSfcConfig::GetStateSetting());
        mainWindow.setGeometry(posX, posY, width, height);
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.move(l);
}
else
{
    mainWindow.showMaximized();
}
```

Comment: Is there no documentation of the behavior?

Comment: You should use `saveGeometry` and `restoreGeometry`, and Qt should be able to take care of all cases including multi-monitor configuration. You can set up a virtual machine with multiple monitors to test the program's behavior.

Comment: i use this and yes it works across 3 monitors for me :)

Comment: @AngryDuck - `this` refers to my code, or the `restoreGeometry() - saveGeometry()` routine?

Comment: sorry should have been clearer, i use save geometry and restore geometry in my software and it works across multiple monitors, i havent had a good look at my code/yours to see if you are implementing correctly, ill look later if i have time